# Как выполнить javascript код в java приложении?

Tags: javascript, java

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста: каким образом можно выполнить скрипт расположенный на удаленном сайте в java приложении? Пытался использовать ScriptEngineManager, но он почему-то ни в какую не хочет работать совсем.
Поставил перед собой задачу написать собственный браузер. Но никак не могу разобраться со скриптами. Вначале скрипты сайта скачиваются в папку. Но когда они начинают выполняться вылетает куча ошибок. Например о том, что нет переменной window, но ведь window это не переменная? Или я что-то не так понимаю?

```
    public void scriptExecutor(){
    try{
        File file = new File("/Users/user/desktop/js");
        File[] f = file.listFiles();
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
        for(int i = 0; i<f.length; i++){
            System.out.println(f[i]);
            engine.eval(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(f[i].getAbsolutePath())));

        }

        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

Comment: `window` - это объект, представляющий окно браузера. Когда скрипт выполняется в Java-приложении, браузера нет, следовательно, нет и `window`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваш ответ. Попробую сделать окно для браузера.

Comment: А не могли бы Вы подсказать, что значит вот эта ошибка? Expected ; but found var?

Comment: Могу только перевести: "Ожидалась точка с запятой, но встретилась переменная". Что-то с синтаксисом. Точно сказать не видя кода невозможно.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо Вам большое. Поводимому неправильно копируется скрипт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас очень амбициозная задача. Создать броузера я бы сказал это высший пилотаж. Гугл и тот построил хром используя webkit. Если у вас задача сделать полноценный броузера то я бы посоветовал не изобретать велосипед и использовать тот-же webkit как движок.
Теперь  по существу вопроса. Ваша проблемма в том, что nashorn это просто движок который может выполнять js. К сожалению, он ничего не знает про контекст броузера, про объект window, он даже не знает ничего про alert. Для того чтобы заставить его исполнять код из страницы вам нужно создать контекст в соответствии со спецификаций для контекста броузера. То есть, вам нужно создать объект  window,  document и кучу других объектов и методов и добавить их в контекст выполнения nashorn.

Для начала взгляните на спецификацию объекта  [window](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/browsers.html#apis-for-creating-and-navigating-browsing-contexts-by-name).

Так же вы можете посмотреть на некоторые существующие проекты похожие на то что вы делаете, например [jxwb](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jxwb/)

Comment: Частенько мониторю Ваши ответы. Спасибо за ваши глубокие и грамотные ответы. Жаль, что SO пока еще не ввел подписки

Comment: Благодарю Вас за Ваш ответ. Действительно для того, что бы выполнялись некоторые javascript необходимо было добавить объекты такие как window, document, и.т.д. И как я понял, добиться полноценного выполнения всех javascript очень даже нетривиальная задача. Еще раз благодарю Вас за ответ, вы очень помогли мне разобраться. Большое спасибо)

Comment: @leprikon , А можно ли будет использовать localstorage в nushorn?

Comment: @ArthurAlunts Не уверен если localstorage поддерживается в nаshorn, скорее всего нет. В любом случае Nashorn больше не поддерживается в Java и удален в JDK15, так что не имеет большого смысла копать в этом направлении.